# what is the order of initialization between dependence variables across files?

Tags: c++

Assume that I have the following code:

```
extern std::string first_string; //defined in another file
std::string another_string(first_string + "some other string");
```

My question is:

**Is it guaranteed by the standard that `first_string` will always be initialized before `another_string`?**

**If not, should code like this be avoided in practice?**

I tried to figure this out by reading C++ standard N3485 Section 3.6 and 3.7. But I did not find a good answer. My great appreciation if you could point me to section of the standard when you draft the answer.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order is undefined.

[C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html):

> suppose you have two static objects x and y which exist in separate
>   source files, say x.cpp and y.cpp. Suppose further that the
>   initialization for the y object (typically the y object's constructor)
>   calls some method on the x object.
>
> That's it. It's that simple.
>
> The tragedy is that you have a 50%-50% chance of dying. If the
>   compilation unit for x.cpp happens to get initialized first, all is
>   well. But if the compilation unit for y.cpp get initialized first,
>   then y's initialization will get run before x's initialization, and
>   you're toast. E.g., y's constructor could call a method on the x
>   object, yet the x object hasn't yet been constructed.

and see [How do I prevent the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order-on-first-use.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's undefined; cf. [What's the "static initialization order fiasco"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). The relevant part in the Standard is §3.6.2 "Initialization of non-local variables", which says

> Otherwise, the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different translation unit.